# Model binding with view in .NetCore project gives object reference null error --

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core, mvvm, object-reference

My problem is as you read in the above title -

My project is in .NetCore. Am doing some calculations and returning some value from my controller to the related view. I have used Product as
model class in my application.

My controller code -

```
    [Route("ProductDetail")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ProductDetail(int id)
    {
        if(id>0)
        {
            Product pEntity = pService.GetProductById(id);
            if(pEntity!=null)
            {
                ViewData["ProductId"] = pEntity.Id;
                return View("ProductDetail", pEntity);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

razor code for the view -

```
    @page
    @using System.ComponentModel

    @model CoreSpeechService.App.Model.Product

   @{
      Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

   <h1>Dettagli del Prodotto</h1>


   <p style="color:#790bf6">Vedi i dettagli del prodotto:  </p>
   <br /><br />


   <div class="row">
   @if(Model!=null)   < ---- at this line
   {
        bla..blablabla ....
        blablabla ...
        bla ..
        blabla ..
    
   }
   </div>
```

My error - : ***'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'***

```
    System.NullReferenceException
    HResult=0x80004003
    Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    Source=CoreSpeechService.App.Views
    StackTrace:
    at CoreSpeechService.App.Pages.Shared.Pages_Shared_ProductDetail.get_Model()
```

Although data is being clearly returned by the method as confirmed, Model gives null at the inopportune moment of loading it. I experimented with inheriting my Product class from PageModel and again removing it. Apparently, that has no effect either way. I went through the official docs of .netcore on model binding. No apparent anomaly.

Where is the error in this flow? If you need more info from my code/project structure, ask for it.

*** the model class Product

```
    public class Product
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       public string product_code { get; set; }

       public string product_name { get; set; }

       public string product_brief { get; set; }

       public int product_price { get; set; }

       public string product_imageurl { get; set; }

       public string SeoUrl { get; set; }

       public int product_rating { get; set; }

   }
```

Comment: It's getting nullref attempting to get the model; can we see your model class? Might be something in one of your property getters? If this were mine, I'd load up Studio and set it to break on all exceptions to get a better idea of where it's REALLY throwing from...

Comment: hi, the model class Product been added. for exp. I tried inheriting it from PageModel to see if that worked. No. So have removed it again. yep I used breakpoints and all that, the call goes from controller to view. nothing breaks in the controller actionmethod portion   @Nikki9696

Comment: anybody got any idea where this could have gone wrong ...  stackoverflow forum contributors ..